# Property id does not exist on type {}

Tags: typescript, react-router

```
  const state = history.location.state;
  const id = state?.id;
```

Following is the typescript error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
```

I am getting the id value from history.location.state i.e from react-router I am sending the id prop as state to history.push("pathname",{id:"some value"}.

So,for this code is working but it throws with a typescript error.

Please help me how to fix the above typescript error.

Comment: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the TypeScript compiler is not aware of the correct type for `history.location.state`. You could try installing types for React:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react @types/react-dom @types/react-router-dom
```

Alternatively, to just get around the error you could force `state` to type `any`:

```
const state = history.location.state;
const id = (state as any)?.id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspect the types, and try to decrypt them.

**TL;DR**

```
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
```

This is what the function definition looks like this:

```
export function useParams<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}>(): Params;
```

If you want an `id` you add an `id`, and so on for any other Params you want.
K is a key in the list of parameters and the type is always a string.